# WP7: Localize the context menu

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, contextmenu

I'm trying to use the ContextMenu control in WP7 with Caliburn Micro. I used the following example:
http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/wp7-context-menus-with-caliburn-micro
I have a "PurchaseListViewModel" approach (second scenario in the example).
Now my problem:
How can I make the menu items localizable. I tried to use the following:

Bind to the resource file which is exposed in the BaseViewModel (works other places in the xaml):

```
Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.MenuDelete, 
                 Source={StaticResource localizedStrings}}"
```

Bind against a property in the ViewModel

```
Header="{Binding MenuDeleteText}"
```

Both approaches didn't work; no text is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that exposing the resource file through a BaseViewModel was wrong. Moving the code to its own file as described here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=VS.92).aspx) seemed to fix the problem. I'm not sure if moving the app to WP 7.1 made a difference as well. If you have some background input why this works, I would be glad to hear about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
Header="{Binding LocalizedResources.MenuDelete, 
                 Source={StaticResource localizedStrings}}"
```

Comment: @Alex, Did you tried by adding a class to provide a static access to the system resource strings as like "localizedStrings". According to the link under "Replacing hard-coded strings with strings in a resource file" heading steps 1,2,3.